# .htaccess - using IF / ELSE / ELSEIF - need some examples / syntax

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to clean up the redirects we have, and I've just discovered the IF / ELSE / ELSEIF functionality. However, I need some help with the syntax or some examples.

Let's say there are 5-10 possible old links, all referring to the same item / SKU. They may look like: `/old_category/old_subcat/widget_SKU12345.html` or
`/special-items/red-widget-SKU12345.php`, or "`/on_sale/special_SKU12345.html`", and so on - basically, a bunch of old links that nonetheless refer to one particular item.

How would I write a statement in .htaccess, along the lines of: "IF the request ends in .html or .php, AND it contains the string "SKU12345", redirect the request to /newcategory/newsubcat/SKU12345"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just this one line to achieve that result.

```
RewriteRule (old_category/old_subcat/widget_|special-items/red-widget-|on_sale/special_)(.+)\.(html|php)$ /newcategory/newsubcat/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ban17: that's a neat example, and I'll keep it in mind for other cases. But what I need is the exact opposite - I don't know the format of the incoming links (in terms of category/subcategory) - the site has gone through multiple structures over the years, and until they show up in the 404s report, there's no way to predict them. The only constant is the SKU (or model name), so I need something that looks for that specific string, regardless of what it's surrounded by.